# wheezy: nis/autofs doesn't work

Tags: nfs, automounting, autofs, debian, nis

I have a few computers with debian lenny on them.
One of them has a nis server: `193.167.1.75`
I can automount my home directory when I log in:

```
>ssh 193.167.1.80 -l myuser
>pwd
 /home/nis/myuser
```

Now, I just installed a debian wheezy on one of them and I can no longer automount home directories (but I still can log in using myuser)

```
>ssh 193.167.1.80 -l myuser
 Could not chdir to home directory /home/nis/myuser: No such file or directory
>pwd
 /
```

What I have done until now:

```
apt-get install nis nfs-common portmap autofs
echo "+::::::" >>/etc/passwd
echo "+::::::::" >>/etc/shadow
echo "+:::" >>/etc/group
echo "mynisserver" > /etc/defaultdomain
echo "ypserver ##.##.##.75" > /etc/yp.conf
nisdomainname mynisserver
/etc/init.d/nis restart
echo "+auto.master" > /etc/auto.master
rm /etc/auto.home
/etc/init.d/autofs restart
```

Any Idea why home directories are still not mounted?

**EDIT 1:**

**Client side (193.167.1.80)**

```
grep -i automount /var/log/messages
grep -i automount /var/log/syslog
```

returns nothing (and no new line when logging in)

```
/etc/init.d/autofs status
[ ok ] automount is running.
```

nsswitch:

```
cat /etc/nsswitch.conf 

passwd:         compat nis
group:          compat nis
shadow:         compat nis

hosts:          files dns nis
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Not sure it has anything to do with it, but just in case:

```
showmount -a
clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Unable to receive: errno 111 (Connection refused)
```

**Server side** (193.167.1.75):

```
cat /etc/exports
/home/nis 193.167.1.0/24(sync,rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

**EDIT2:**

I tried to manually mount nfs on 193.167.1.80 with root. It worked. Now I need to figure out why autofs don't do it automatically:

```
mount -t nfs -o rw 193.167.1.75:/home/nis /home/nis
```

Comment: Anything useful in the logs?

Comment: Nothing in `/var/log/messages`. Where can I look otherwise?

Comment: `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: Nothing in `/var/log/syslog` either. No new line when logging in and nothing from `grep -i automount /var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have not NFS exported any of the filesystems.  Just putting items in an automap does NOT automatically export anything.  Check your `/etc/exports` file on the source server.

Also you need to indicate what the contexts of your two automount maps are.

Also, you should indicate the contents of `/etc/nsswitch`.  If you have this file set wrong, your NIS is never going to be consulted.

Comment: I edited my question. For `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, I added the first 4 `nis` keywords. But it works without it on all other computers.

Comment: Try adding `automount:      files nis` to your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file.

Comment: BTW: `compat` is fine for `passwd`, `group`, and `shadow` lines in your `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.  As this already implies `nis`.

Comment: Well, I think I broke something (nothing to do with the last file editing): I can't restart `/etc/init.d/nis` now.

Comment: ...nothing a reboot can't fix. But still no luck: home directory is not mounted

Comment: have you tried `exportfs -a` again on the server side?  Just to make sure things got exported.

Comment: I tried this command. autofs still doesn't work, but I can manually mount nfs (I edited question)

Answer (score 1):

I see this on my system as well.  In my situation, when I log in, I see that NIS has started (ypwhich returns the server's name), but the auto-mounter didn't read any of the maps.  Restarting autofs (/etc/init.d/autofs restart) takes care of the problem until my next reboot.

I haven't figured out why this is happening on my PC.

I've seen it on some RedHat systems running on a subnet where broadcast access to the NIS server is unavailable.  They are configured with a yp.conf that looks like "domain MYDOMAIN server MYNISSERVER".  I found that at the point in the boot sequence where ypbind is launched, the DNS resolution for MYNISSERVER fails and YP doesn't bind.  Changing MYNISSERVER from a DNS name to a numeric IP address or adding a line to /etc/hosts for MYNISSERVER works there.

On my Debian box, however, this isn't the issue.  Ypbind does start successfully.  According to the boot-time messages, it fails, but continues in the background.  I suspect it succeeds some time after autofs is started, hence the problem.

When I edited /etc/init.d/nis so the delay between retries is 5 seconds, the problem didn't change, so it's not simply a matter of not waiting long enough.

I think, looking at log files, that the startup code is attempting to start NIS before the NetworkManager/DHCP has finished trying to bring up the interface, meaning there is no interface for it to try and connect over.

I was able to work around the problem by adding the following two lines to my /etc/rc.local:

```
/etc/init.d/nis start
/etc/init.d/autofs restart
```

SO clearly, something loading between the initial attempt to bring up NIS and the end of the startup sequence (at rc.local) should have been running earlier.  According to the content of /etc/rc5.d, this could only be nfs-kernel-server (which I'm not using), cron, and minissdpd, but none of them make sense to me.

So...  I don't know exactly what's causing your problem, but I may have been able to present you with a workaround.  Hopefully someone with more experience than I can add to this and figure out the real cause of the problem that I (and you, probably) are observing.

Comment: +1. I no longer have access on these computers, but it's an interesting diagnosis that I will keep in mind for next time.